# JAVA Warning - Dereferancing Possible Null Pointer. How do I properly get rid of this warning?

Tags: java, null, dereference

I am learning JAVA.

I cannot seem to find a way to get rid of this 'possible null derefence' warning.  I have created fOut in the proper scope as null, otherwise I get a 'may not have been initialized' error.

I was unable to find an simple example that would help me fix this.  I know it is probably a simple answer.

Thank you.

```
public static int waveToFile (String filename, byte[] byteWave)
{
    FileOutputStream fOut = null;


    File file = new File (filename);
    try
    {
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {

    }
    try{
        fOut.write(byteWave); //THIS IS WARNING of POSSIBLE DE-REFERENCE 
        fOut.close();                                  //OF NULL POINTER
       }
         catch (IOException e)
             {

             }


    return mErr;
}
```

Comment: Why are there separate `try catch` blocks?

Comment: Is your above code compilable?

Comment: There are separate try catch blocks because I am a newb! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact is that you are constructing the file object and using it in two different try-catch blocks. So if this fails:

```
fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

no value will be assigned to `fOut`, the first `catch` will handle the exception and the excution will continue with:

```
fOut.write(byteWave); //THIS IS WARNING of POSSIBLE DE-REFERENCE 
fOut.close();                                  //OF NULL POINTER
```

Hah! `fOut` is `null` because the previous block failed. The warning is well justified.

First of all, wrap the two operations in the same try-catch block:

```
FileOutputStream fOut = null;
File file = new File (filename);

try {
    fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
    fOut.write(byteWave);
    fOut.close();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    // Do something
}
```

This piece of code has still a problem: if `write` fails and an exception is thrown, `close`
will never be called. You can use a `finally` block to ensure that the file is closed no matter what or, better, a closing context:

```
File file = new File (filename);

try (FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file)){
    fOut.write(byteWave);
}
catch (IOException e) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: finally {
            if (fOut != null) {
                fOut.close();  //THIS PRODUCES Unreported iOException, must be caught or declared to be thrown
            }
          Did I do this properly???

Comment: Use the second snippet from the answer, it's much more concise than a `finally` block with a null test.

Answer (score 5):

If an exception is thrown `fOut` can be `null`. Therefore the compiler is warning you.

To avoid it, check that it is not `null`:

```
finally {
    if(fOut != null) {
        fOut.close();
    }
}
```

As a side note:

- do not just swallow exception (catching them doing nothing)
- put the `close` in a finally block to make sure it is executed
- do not write in `fOut` if there has been an exception

You can also use a [try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) which is perfectly safe and does the work for you:

```
try(fOut = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
    fOut.write(byteWave);
} catch(IOException e) {
    // do something with e
}
```

Comment: +1 I like this answer better than mine, so am deleting mine in favor of this one.

Answer (score 0):

you need two try block.

```
public static int waveToFile (String filename, byte[] byteWave)
{
    FileOutputStream fOut = null;


    File file = new File (filename);
    try
    {
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fOut.write(byteWave); 
        if(fOut !=null){
          fOut.close();  
        }

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {

    }
    return mErr;
}
```